# Swiperefreshlayout with fragment not scrolling up

Tags: android, scroll, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

I have a layout with some preferences. It works correctly in portrait, but not in landscape. I want this layout to refresh with a swiperefreshlayout, and does work. But as i i say in the title, it doesnt scroll up.

Ive been playing with a normal LinearLayout, with a RelativeLayout, using the swiperefreshlayout as the root view, playing with weights, ... but nothing. It either doesnt scroll up, or doesnt show the preferences correctly (only the 1st title). Dont know what else to try.

I should also say, i want this screen to keep a linearlayout at the bottom, fixed there. So, only the preferences would scroll.

Heres what i have right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edittexts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setwallpaperbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onActivarClick"
            android:text="@string/setwallpaperbuton"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextlocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextupdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/swipelayout"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edittexts">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <fragment
                android:name="es.jnsoft.nowweather.PreferencesFragment"
                android:id="@+id/preferencesfragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout="@xml/settings"/>

        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html),

> [SwipeRefreshLayout] should be made the parent of the view that will be
>   refreshed as a result of the gesture and can only support one direct
>   child.

This clause is violated in your layout.